# jquery ui autocomplete not populating from remote datasource

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My first stackoverflow post! So I cannot figure out why this is not working. It was working in the past but it does not now, don't know what changed. The JSON is returning correctly it's just not populating the drop down. 
Here is the html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search').autocomplete({
source: 'search.php',
minLength: 2
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="search">Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
mysql_select_db('symfony',$con);

$autocomplete_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["term"]);

$sql = "SELECT name FROM Artist WHERE name LIKE '%$autocomplete_value%' UNION
        SELECT name FROM Event WHERE name LIKE '%$autocomplete_value%'";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;  

$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($results, array( 'name' => $row['name']) );

}

json_encode($results);
?>
```

EDIT**
My coworker helped me figure it out. I need to change

```
array_push($results, array( 'name' => $row['name']) );
```

to

```
array_push($results, array( 'value' => $row['name']) );
```

Now it works!

Comment: Any JS error? Have you tried to copy/paste your JSON code returned from your server to the autocomplete source parameter insetad of "search.php" to validate it?

Comment: My coworker helped me figure it out. I need to change

Comment: Post your resolution as an answer, then accept that answer  :)